# Intersection types in Flow give strange error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have following types defined in Flow:

```
export type MovementInfo = { id: string, x: number, y: number, s: [number, number] }
export type TypeInfo = { eType: string, idx: number }
export type CreationInfo = TypeInfo & MovementInfo
export type CmdNew = { type: 'new' } & CreationInfo
```

In VSCode Flow underlines both `TypeInfo` and `MovementInfo` in 3rd line and `{ type: 'new' }` in 
 4th and gives me following errors for each:

```
[flow] object type (This type is incompatible with an implicitly-returned undefined.)
```

Using Flow 0.49.1

Is it me or Flow doing something stupid?

Comment: Nothing about those types throws on their own, so it has to do with the code that is using them. Try to make an example that demonstrates the issue in https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAWTgDcMBbDAO0IElmo4wBeMAbzABLACYAuMAGdC+IcwDmAGjBYJzAK4MARhnzLSazTr1SJAbQ3bdyy8YC6YAL6ZcBYmQpgAKuQwcuvAJgGD4UEtKyCsqiqmC2uk4ueEQkvmAAwvgYAIaEQnDM-tx8oX6c3ABk1HSMLOzlSW6pnukMIgByGEh8gh4YEgDkzF0DTmBVmTl5BUVAA

Comment: The error might be poorly positioned, but usually I see that error when a function claims to return a non-`undefined` type but there is an implicit return. When control flow can reach the end of the function without an explicit return statement, it will implicitly return `undefined`. I think this is what Flow is complaining about. See if there is a function that returns this type but may implicitly return `undefined`